# How to make gradient background in UITableViewCell in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have followed the tutorial below to use CAGradientLayer to make gradient background in UITableViewCell.

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/08/adding-shadow-effects-to-uitableview.html

Besides this tutorial, is there any other resources in this topic ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please mark this question as answered?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The always-awesome Ray Wenderlich did a tutorial on changing UITableViewCells and includes a gradient.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2033/core-graphics-101-lines-rectangles-and-gradients

If you want a quick and way, here's some code:

```
//include #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> in the header…

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[DayCalendarCellView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        gradient.frame = cell.bounds;
        gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor], (id)[[UIColor redColor]CGColor], nil];
        [cell.layer addSublayer:gradient];
    }        
    return cell;
}
```

You can change the colors but this will give you a good idea…

Good luck!

Comment: There's an error in this code. The colors need to be cast to type id when they're added to the NSArray. See below.

[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, nil];

Other than that it works great. Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: Be careful with this approach if you require on other layers / subviews of UITableViewCell, as your gradient could draw over them.

Comment: Good Answer but I am facing problem with this cell text is not displaying?Could u help me regarding this problem.

Comment: The problem might be that you need to add the sublayer at index 0 OR add it to cell.backgroundView.layer. 

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks works perfectly...Just need to add following line [cell.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0]; instead of [cell.layer addSublayer:gradient];

Comment: @Peter Hajas, hi, i got this problem here. I added a layer here in my customized cell, but I shows like a mask over the cell, how I can solve the problem, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create 1px image of X height.

add UIView object in cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

colorWithPatterImage method of uicolor in UIView setbackgroundcolor method.

Comment: This is a great way to do it. use `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]`

Answer (score 2):

Follow Jacob's answer and to set background color of a UIButton or any View use:

```
[button.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

instead of:

```
[button.layer addSublayer:gradient];
```

Comment: I also had to set the background color to transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Peronally I would create a gradient image in Photoshop or gimp, and then use that as the background. Should work fine as long as the cells are of a predictable size.

Comment: This doesn't work if you need a gradient of variable height. Also, if the same effect can be achieved programmatically, it might be wise to do so, since it makes the .ipa smaller. Just my 2 cents