# UITableViewCell Gradient Layer Covering Delete Button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cagradientlayer

I'm using this answer to create a gradient background for a table view cell

[How to make gradient background in UITableViewCell in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944478/how-to-make-gradient-background-in-uitableviewcell-in-ios)

```
-(void)addGradientBackgroundWithColor:(UIColor *)color {
    if (!self.gradientLayer) {
        self.gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        self.gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds;
        self.gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.5f);
        self.gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.5f);
    }
    self.gradientLayer.colors = @[(id)[[color hmf_makeLightHighlight] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    [self.layer insertSublayer:self.gradientLayer atIndex:0];

}
```

The problem is that when I do a swipe to delete gesture, the gradient layer seems to cover the delete button.

Is there a way to fix this?

[image] [image]

Comment: One workaround would be hiding gradientLayer when action buttons are shown. Also there should be a way to change the z order of items. insertSublayer index is 0, maybe if you have this index as 1 and have all the other items in cell in a view with z position 2 etc then it could work.

Comment: You can move the Gradient as a overlay view and catch the swipe gesture, It's a very complex workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this fixed my issue

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    // resize your layers based on the view's new bounds
    self.gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you insert gradient layer into UITableViewCell. I think insert into contentView of UITableViewCell may solve your problem.

Comment: I just tried [self.contentView.layer insertSublayer:self.gradientLayer atIndex:0]; 
It did not make a difference :(